# Expresión Regular Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, flex, jflex

Necesito ayuda con una expresión regex, estoy apenas comenzando y necesito que me identifique las siguientes palabras:

```
Palabras que NO tienen dos vocales seguidas, y terminan en vocal
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Mejor que pedir que te solucionen los problemas es pedir que te ayuden a solucionarlos. Míra [como hacer una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sería bueno que compartieras que has intentado.

Answer (score 1):

Para serte franco no se como explicar como funciona esta porción de regex, así que evité responder antes:

```regex
^((?!hede).)*$
```

Acá explican como funciona: [stackoverflow: Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/13636459)

**Lo que hace es detectar lineas completas que no contenga el patrón especificado.**

---

Pero empleando esa porción de regex es relativamente fácil proseguir, solo debes ajustarla para que en vez de no detectar un patrón por línea, lo haga por palabras...

Así que el patrón que debes poner dentro es el de dos vocales repetidas `[aeiou]{2}`. y remplazar `^` y `$` con la sintaxis de frontera de palabra `\b`, si quieres una vocal al final sería `[aeiou]\b`

Quedaría así:

```regex
\b((?![aeiou]{2}).)*[aeiou]\b
```

Comprobar en [regex101: r/WUA5Uo/1](https://regex101.com/r/WUA5Uo/1)

Answer (score 0):

**La expresión regular:**

`(?<![a-zA-ZáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜñÑ])(?![a-zA-ZáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜñÑ]*[aeiouáéíóúüAEIOUÁÉÍÓÚÜ]{2})[a-zA-ZáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜñÑ]*[aeiouáéíóúüAEIOUÁÉÍÓÚÜ](?![a-zA-ZáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜñÑ])`

**El análisis de la expresión regular:**

`(?<![a-zA-ZáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜñÑ])`  *Lookbehind: No permite un carácter alfabético antes del primer carácter de una palabra*

`(?!`                          *Lookahead: No permite dos vocales consecutivas entre el inicio y el final de una palabra*

`[a-zA-ZáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜñÑ]*`        *Entre cero y un número indefinido de caracteres alfabéticos*

`[aeiouáéíóúüAEIOUÁÉÍÓÚÜ]{2}`    *Dos vocales consecutivas (May/Min no-acentuadas/acentuadas)*

`)`

`[a-zA-ZáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜñÑ]*`      *Entre cero y un número indefinido de caracteres alfabéticos*

`[aeiouáéíóúüAEIOUÁÉÍÓÚÜ]`     *Último carácter: Una vocal, minúscula o mayúscula, acentuada o no*

`(?![a-zA-ZáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜñÑ])`   *Lookahead: No permite un carácter alfabético después del último carácter de una palabra*

Nótese que esta expresión regular funciona para palabras que pudieran encontrarse potencialmente en un diccionario del idioma español.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Probar en Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lAI4TL/1)

Comment: La idea esta muy bien, solo cambiaría que `\p{L}` con el flag `u` (unicode) representaría cualquier letra de cualquier lenguage. El flag `i` (insensitive) ya incluiría mayúsculas y minúsculas, de manera que la regex `(?<![\p{L}])(?![\p{L}]*[aeiouáéíóúü]{2})[\p{L}]*[aeiouáéíóúü](?![\p{L}])` con los flags `ug` representaría lo mismo pero mas corto.

Comment: Otra cosa es que el link de regex101 es del flavor python, en JavaScript con mis propuestas de cambios https://regex101.com/r/LfCLMe/1

Answer (score 0):

Pongamos `V` por la expresión por *vocal* y `C` por la de *consonante* (u otro símbolo que podría encontrarse en una palabra). Con esto, la expresión deseada sería `C*(VC+)*V`. Debe ser claro que es imposible que haya dos `V`s seguidas, y que cualquier otra palabra pasa.

Solo falta decidir que son `C` y `V`, exactamente, pero ambas deben ser clases de caracteres (p. ej. `[aeiouyAEIOUY]` o lo mismo con tildes si estás usando una codificación que lo permite.)

Answer (score -1):

Vale, ya me he familiarizado un poco y según las pruebas que he hecho esto debería valer (en mi caso para jflex):

```
[a-zA-Z]*([AEIOUaeiou][aeiou]|[AEIOUaeiou][aeiou][a-zA-Z]*[AEIOUaeiou])
```

Comment: la palabra "que" pasa la expresión y no debería.